# Only One Of Two UITableViews Are Loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have two tableviews and only the person tableview is loading data.  How do i handle multiple uitableviews on one view controller?  Below is what i have so far with my .m file.  TABLE VIEW PERSONS is the only log return I'm getting I should also get TABLE VIEW EXPECTATIONS logged if this was working right (as well as data loading into that expectations tableview of course)

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    if(tableView == self.listPersonTableView)
        return  1;
    else if(tableView == self.listExpectationsTableView)
        return  1;
    else
        return 0;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if(tableView == self.listPersonTableView)
        return  [arrayOfPersons count];
    else if(tableView == self.listExpectationsTableView)
        return  [arrayOfExpectations count];
    else
        return 0;

}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(!cell){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if(tableView == self.listPersonTableView){
        Person *person = [arrayOfPersons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.textLabel.text = person.personName;
    NSLog(@"TABLE VIEW PERSONS");
        return cell;
}
    else if(tableView == self.listExpectationsTableView){
        Expectations *expectation = [arrayOfExpectations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.textLabel.text = expectation.expText;

    NSLog(@"TABLE VIEW EXPECTATIONS");
    return cell;
    }
    else
        return cell;
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    if (tableView == _listPersonTableView) {


        NSLog(@"Row In Person TableView Selected Nothing To Do HERE YET");


    }
    else if(tableView == self.listExpectationsTableView){

        NSLog(@"Row In Expectations TableView Selected Nothing To Do HERE YET");

    }else{
        NSLog(@"Do Nothing");
    }

}
```

EDIT: So from comments below i have found that my arrayOfExpectations is 0 but don't know why.  See my while loop below.  I know its looping twice because the NSLog is showing twice but with 0 as the array count?

```
while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW){

                NSString *expText = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,4)];

                NSString *expID = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,3)];

                NSString *efeID = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,0)];



                Expectations *expectations = [[Expectations alloc]init];
                [expectations setExpText:expText];
                [expectations setExpID:expID];
                [expectations setEfeID:efeID];

                [arrayOfExpectations addObject:expectations];
                NSLog(@"Expectations Count: %lu", (unsigned long)[arrayOfExpectations count]);

            }
```

Comment: You should be using isEqual: to compare objects. Also, make sure that [arrayOfExprectations count] > 0 because NSLog(@"TABLE VIEW EXPECTATIONS"); will not be called unless tableView:numberOfRowsInSection returns at least 1.

Comment: Is the `dataSource` and `delegate` set for both tables? Does `arrayOfExpectations` have any values?

Comment: @Jonathan Not in this case. In this case using `==` to see which table is being used is correct.

Comment: @rmaddy, You're right. I stand corrected.

Comment: @Jonathan You use `==` (like in this case) to see if two variables point to the same object. You use `isEqual:` to see if two objects represent the same value. They each have a specific use. It would be inappropriate to use `isEqual:` in this case.

Comment: @rmaddy, Oh ok. Thank you for elaborating.

Comment: arrayOfExpectations is 0 but why?  Im looping through an sql statement and i know its looping twice because the NSLog is showing ExpectationsCount: 0 twice.  whats wrong with my addObject:expectations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same problem once. I check every single thing to see why the table was not getting populated. I checked the Delegate and DataSource of the UITableView is connected. Array has data in it. And every possible thing to display the data, but in vain. Then i just tried and used tags for UITableViews, and I dont know how but it worked. It somehow worked. Since that day I used tags for UITableView and I never had to look back.

You can try the same.

```
if (tableView.tag == 1){
    ...Do something here...

}
```

Try and check. Hope this works for you as it did for me. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem before. This could be caused by the NSMutableArray is not allocated and initialized. Make sure you have `arrayOfExpectations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` somewhere in your code.